# How to display images from /vendors/assets on Heroku

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku

In `/vendor/assets/stylesheets/jquery_ui/images` are all images from **jQuery-UI** library. On localhost works me everything well, but when I deploy app (Rails 3.2) to heroku, so there are not displayed any of images placed in the **vendor** directory.

I tried placed these images to the `/public` directory, `/app/assets/` directory, also run the command `rake assets:precompile`, but nothing works me.

jQuery running on Heroku well, but its images still not.

What am I still missing? I have already not idea, what to try yet...

Thank you

Comment: are you sure the precompiled assets have been added and pushed to heroku with `git commit`?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the image path which is created after parsing using inspect element. the path is not properly created obviously.